# function for finding mode in c++

Tags: c++, statistics

i made about 90% from the problem but the issue is when there is no mode 
that what i did , i if there is no mode to print -1 i tried a lot but always fail i tast case

this the function I wrote

```
void mode(int arr[], int size)
{
    int max_count = 0; // for the most numbers occuer
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Mode is: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int count = 1;
        /*to count how many times num occuer to compare it with max count
          it is inside the loop to start each time from 1*/
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                count++;
        if (count > max_count)
            max_count = count;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int count = 1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                count++;
        if (count == max_count)
            cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: There's always a mode in non-empty array, but there can be more than one, for example 1 and 2 in `[1, 1, 2, 2]`

Comment: Please provide a [mre] along with the expected and actual output. On the code side, you should only need to add a short `main` function that defines the array to be used as input to `mode`.